# Volume of a ball after linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}$  be a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at zero with radius $r$.

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ matrix.  I am interested in how does the maximum radius of a set $\mathcal{Y}=A \mathcal{B}$ behave. 
That is
\begin{align}
R=\max_{ x \in \mathcal{Y}} \|x\|. 
\end{align}

Things that I tried.

Let $H$ be invertible then it is not difficult to show that
\begin{align}
R =|det(A)|^{\frac{1}{n}} r
\end{align}

This can be infered from $Vol(\mathcal{Y})= |det(A)|Vol(\mathcal{B})$.

My question: Is what happens if $A$ is not-invertible? 
Specifically, can we give lower bounds on $R$? Also, can this bound be connected to the rank of $A$?

Comment: Showing that for a bijective linear map $A$ $$\max_{x\in \mathcal B} \lVert A x\rVert =\lvert \det A\rvert^{1/n} r$$ is **very** difficult, because it is *false*. Consider the unit ball and the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&\frac12\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli OK. Thanks. I see this now

Answer (score 1):

We may scale $\mathcal{B}$ so that it has radius 1, by considering $\mathcal{B}/r.$ Now if $A=U\Sigma V^{*}$ is the singular value decomposition of $A,$ then the largest singular value of $A,$ $\sigma_{1}(A)=\max_{x\in\mathcal{B}/r}\|Ax\|_{2}=\max_{y\in\mathcal{Y}/r}\|y\|_{2}.$ Then $\max_{z\in\mathcal{Y}}\|z\|_{2}=\max_{ry\in\mathcal{Y}}\|ry\|_{2}=r\sigma_{1}(A).$

Note that this does not depend on the invertibility of $A$.

Comment: So, if $A$ is not full rank. The maximum radius is zero, right?

Comment: Not necessarily: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ will map $(r,0)$ to $(r,r),$ so the maximum radius is $r\sqrt{2}.$